# Reading Potentiometer value via Nucleo-board F070RB

Tags: c++, mbed

I am trying to read the voltage output from my potentiometer connected to Pin PA_5 of my Nucleo Board (https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F072RB/).

The AnalogIn emits a float number.

Here is my code:

```
#include "mbed.h"

AnalogIn myPot(PA_5);

float value = 0.0f;

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        value = myPot;
        printf("%f\n", value);
        thread_sleep_for(2000);
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that when i am trying to display "value", it only displays "%f".

What have done wrong?

I was therefore expecting a float value between 0 and 5V.

Answer (score 0):

Printf takes a lot of resources for an embedded system, and printing floats even moreso. Thus, mbed has disabled printing floats by default in printf/sprintf as some targets may not be able to support it.

You can enable printing of floats by setting the config parameter: `minimal-printf-enable-floating-point` to `true`.

Alternatively, you can instead read the analog input as a 16 bit integer and print that.

Lastly, I should add that this will not print a floating point value between 0V -> 5V. It will print a value from 0 -> 1 which is a percent of the reference voltage. If you want to print it as a voltage you can multiple by the referenc voltage.

See mbed [readme about minimal-printf](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/platform/source/minimal-printf/README.md)